# C# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word problem with Word.Application()

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-word

I have a problem. When i mouse hover to row Word.Application(), an Application belongs to class Word.ApplicationClass.ApplicationClass(), but must belong to Microsoft.Office.Interpop.Word.Application(). How to fix it?

I downloaded the pocket Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word version 15.0.4797.1004. So, when i am starting to work with word, i have an issue "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: "Could not load file or assembly 'office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'. Can't find the file"

```
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using Session2._1.Models;
using System;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.IO;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using System.Runtime.ConstrainedExecution;
using System.IO.Packaging;


namespace Session2._1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для Spec.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Spec : Window
    {
        private void Print_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var Application = new Word.Application();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to use

```
private void Print_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
}
```

but that didn't work.

Comment: Is Word 15 actually installed on the machine?

Comment: Yes, i used it before in projects, and everything worked

Answer (score 0):

It's a runtime callable wrapper for part of the COM interop. You can't construct an instance of it the way you would a typical class. You need to get it from a running instance of Word. Usually this would be done in the context of a VSTO add-in.

It's not clear what you are trying to do. If you are making an add-in then you can use the VSTO add-in project template in Visual Studio. This would take care of the plumbing for you. If this is what you are trying to do, then I'd suggest seeing if you can accomplish the same thing with office.js and using that instead if feasible.

If you are making something that works directly with Word documents outside of the context of the Word application, then you might look at the OpenXML Sdk.